# requested yarn user xxx not found when running distcp from hadoop to GCS

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, distcp

when i try and run the distcp command

```
 hadoop distcp /user/a.txt gs://user/a.txt
```

i get the message

```
 ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered
main : run as user is xxx
main : requested yarn user is xxx
User xxx not found
```

Comment: Usually means your namenode  machine has no Unix user account with that name. Refer your OS documentation on how to add users

Comment: thanks @OneCricketeer if i do hadoop fs -ls /user I can see my username

drwx------   - xxx    supergroup                   0 2023-03-09 14:13 /user/xxx

does that mean I have a linux user account already or not really?

Comment: By default, HDFS is not secured. Those usernames are only strings, and unrelated to users found from `sudo cat /etc/passwd` on the namenode

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer i have two namenodes one in active and one in standby mode. i created a linux user on both nodes and when i run it now i get the error


Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://devhaservice1/user/xxx/.staging/_distcp1493657434/fileList.seq

Comment: Okay. Progress... I cannot recall how staging files are generated for distcp. Feel free to [edit] your post with the new error

Comment: You may need to `hadoop fs -chown -R xxx:supergroup /user/xxx` and make sure you run `distcp` as `xxx` user

Comment: okay @OneCricketeer next error im now getting after doing the chown command

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't run retriable-command: Copying distcp /user/a.txt to gs://user/a.txt 
        at 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error getting 'user' bucket
        at ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252430/discussion-between-leon-and-onecricketeer).

Comment: I don't use Google storage, so cannot really help with that. Maybe a credentials issue defined in core-site.xml? Typically, you distcp a whole folder, not one file